# Picking up random value in Python code from outer PostgreSQL table data

Tags: python, postgresql, random

I just started Python learning and need advise. The task is to pick in code a random login ID (text less or equal than 8 characters) from the PostgreSQL table. The table has few thousand of records. In Python there is a way using random.choice() function and the list of values, e.g.:

```
import random
alias = ['gahandav', 'goremart', 'fletchea', 'wilderal', 'clarkevi', ...] # over 8000 records
for num in range(100)
    randomvalue = random.choice(alias)
    print (randomvalue)
```

But how to populate this list with PG table data (it's quite large)? Or is there a way to pick up random value inside PG and "pass" it to the Python? Please advise the direction.

Comment: See [String functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) and [Math functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html). `select col_val from some_table where length(col_val) <= 8 order by random() limit 1`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver; Thanks a lot!